# How to break the string in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have the databases name in following format

```
username_databasename
```

Now I want to put separate database backups in username directory like

```
/backups/username/backup
```

How can I get the usernamae from that string

I also want that if string does not contain underscore (_) then the backup should go to

```
/backups/others/backup
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
username=others
if echo $name | grep '_'; then
 username=$(echo $name | cut -d'_' -f 1)
fi
```

Comment: thanks for that . i also want that if (_) is not present then default username = others

Answer (score 5):

Jonathan Leffler has a nice, clean answer.

If you don't want to use sed for some reason, you can replace the `$(echo | sed)` bit with:

```
username="${fullname%_*}"
```

which does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a variation on:

```
case $fullname in
(*_*) username=$(echo $fullname | sed 's/_.*//');;
(*)   username=others;;
esac
backupdir="/backups/$username/backup"
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can use arrays, like so:

```
str="a/bc/def"
IFS="/" arr=($str)
echo ${arr[0]}; # prints 'a'
echo ${arr[1]}; # prints 'bc'
echo ${arr[2]}; # prints 'def'

echo ${arr[@]}; # prints 'a bc def'
```

If you want to split the string by a different "separator", just change IFS="/" line to that separator, eg

```
str="a,bc,def"
IFS="," arr=($str)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `cut`, `grep`, `sed` or `awk` here. Just use `bash`'s inbuilt parameter substitution:

```
db_name=username_databasename

username=others
if [[ ${db_name} =~ '_' ]]; then
   username=${db_name%%_*} 
fi
backup_dir=/backups/${username}/backup
```

I prefer to stick to just one language per script, with as few forks as possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk:

```
username = `echo $name | awk -F"_" '{print $1}'`
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `bash`-only solution with no potentially expensive calls to external programs (only important if you do it a lot, which may not be the case here):

```
pax> export x=a ; if [[ "${x%%_*}" != "${x}" ]]; then
...>    export bkpdir=/backups/${x%%_*}/backup
...> else
...>    export bkpdir=/backups/others/backup
...> fi
pax> echo "     ${bkpdir}"
     /backups/others/backup

pax> export x=a_b ; if [[ "${x%%_*}" != "${x}" ]]; then
...>    export bkpdir=/backups/${x%%_*}/backup
...> else
...>    export bkpdir=/backups/others/backup
...> fi
pax> echo "     ${bkpdir}"
     /backups/a/backup
```

The `if` statement detects if there's an underscore by checking a modified string against the original. If there is an underscore, they will be different.

The `${x%%_*}` gives you the string up to the removal of the longest `_*` pattern (in other words, it deletes everything from the first underscore to the end).

---

A (slightly) simpler variant would be:

```
export bkpdir=/backups/others/backup
if [[ "${x%%_*}" != "${x}" ]]; then
    export bkpdir=/backups/${x%%_*}/backup
fi
```

Comment: In which way is it bash-only? `%%` operation is defined in POSIX. Also, you don't need to put "export" everywhere. In fact, I don't see why would you want to put it at all, since you don't do any external program calls.

Comment: I meant bash-only as in no external calls to grep or sed. I didn't mean it would only work in bash. And I generally use export where there's doubt since there's few things more annoying than trying to figure out why a started process can't see the environment variable. My use of export has nothing to do with my answer however - it's simple supporting code to give a full working sample.

Comment: ha ha i think i need to learn so many things in order to understand ur answer. Can you please give me some tutorial to understand export , %% thing.i also don't know much seb ,awk. any tutts which can make me write program like u. Although i got my answer in simple steps but i love the way how things can be done

Comment: @Mirage, quick tute, given comment size limits: 1/ Setting a variable doesn't make it available to sub-processes that you start later. To do that, you need to export it. 2/ `%%` is a bash thing, you're probably best off buying the OReilly bash book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009656 and the also have a moderately good book called "sed & awk". Or, alternatively, you can spend thirty years in the IT industry like I have :-)

Comment: Thanks buddy but i have seen that experience really speaks